# Is there a way to pass the context object to a function in template in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

For example, if we something like this:

```
@click="store.selectItem(item.hash, context, $event)"
```

You can see in this case, we are using a function outside the scope of the component. Is there any way that we could pass in the component context in the same way as we pass in the $event?

Comment: You can try to pass `this` but this is certainly a mistake in design. Whatever you try to do, needs to be done in more conventional way.

Comment: @EstusFlask you're right. I've reworked it to be `itemClicked(item.hash, $event)`. Which then triggers the outside scope function within the setup() function. This allows me to pass in the context at that point.